# How do I use the ostream::seekp function to find an object with a certain id# in a random access file?

Tags: c++

I have a Person class that has the private data members **id, lastName, firstName**, and **age**. I created file containing 50 Person objects with "unassigned" and 0 for the data members, using this function:

```
void createPersonFile(ofstream &outputPersonFile){

    Person blankPerson;
    blankPerson.setID(0);
    blankPerson.setFirstName("unassigned");
    blankPerson.setLastName("unassigned");
    blankPerson.setAge(0);

    for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
        outputPersonFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&blankPerson),
        sizeof(Person));
}
```

I have to create functions that will let me write a new Person, update a Person, delete a Person, and display a Person but I don't know **how to use the seekp function** to write them. This is what I have for a function that will write a new Person to the file. I already have two separate functions not shown here that I am calling to open input/output files.

```
void writeNewPerson(ofstream &outputPersonFile){

    int inputID;
    int userNumber;
    string userInput;
    Person person;

    cout << "Please enter a record number (1-50): ";
    cin >> inputID;

    cout << "Enter the person's first name: ";
    cin >> userInput;
    person.setFirstName(userInput);

    cout << "Enter the person's last name: ";
    cin >> userInput;
    person.setLastName(userInput);

    cout << "Enter the person's age: ";
    cin >> userInput;
    person.setAge(userNumber);
    cout << endl;

    outputPersonFile.seekp( WHAT GOES HERE??? );
    outputPersonFile.write( reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&person), sizeof(Person) );

 }
```

I'm stumped on how to use the seekp function above...

Person.h

```
// Person.h
// Class Person definition
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
    // default Person constructor
    Person(int = 0, string = "unassigned", string = "unassigned", int = 0);

    // accessor functions for id
    void setID(int);
    int getID() const;

    // accessor functions for lastName
    void setLastName(string);
    string getLastName() const;

    // accessor functions for firstName
    void setFirstName(string);
    string getFirstName() const;

    // accessor functions for age
    void setAge(int);
    int getAge() const;
private:
    int id;
    char lastName[15];
    char firstName[15];
    int age;
}; // end class Person

#endif
```

Comment: a) Show the class, b) Without proper serialization, this is just nonsense. Casting some random object to bytes is not proper.

Comment: a) With this class, the serialization part will work at least at your computer. Is that enough? No? ... b) What does eg. `setFirstName` with a name longer than 15? Crashing?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know serialization was needed.

Comment: a) yes that would be enough.   b) My professor said to assume the user won't enter a name longer than 15 characters.

Comment: Transforming an object to a byte sequence is called "serialization". Of course it is needed if you´re doing exactly that. ... Anyways, seekp: 0 Byte from ios_base::end. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp/